# How to install laravel using composer in a live server without any issue?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, cpanel

I am trying to install Laravel in my cPanel via `php composer.phar` command. But installation does not complete. The installation failed by showing:

```
To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
     -/opt/alt/php56/etc/php.ini
     -/opt/alt/php56/link/conf/alt_php.ini
You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.
```

How can I remove this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Most shared hosting companies don't all PHP extensions (required for Laravel) by default; you may have to pay something more for some of them (PHP extensions).

That said, you may be able to get access to your `php.ini` file so as to make sure all Laravel required extensions are installed and enabled depending on your contractual agreements.

Currently, [server requirements](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4#server-requirements) for Laravel as at version 5.4 are:

- PHP >= 5.6.4
- OpenSSL PHP Extension
- PDO PHP Extension
- Mbstring PHP Extension
- Tokenizer PHP Extension
- XML PHP Extension

In your very instance (Laravel 5.2), your server must meet the following [requirements](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2#server-requirements):

- PHP >= 5.5.9
- OpenSSL PHP Extension
- PDO PHP Extension
- Mbstring PHP Extension
- Tokenizer PHP Extension

One other thing to consider after enabling the required PHP extension, you *may* need to restart your server so as your modifications take a full effect.

Also, on shared hosting, some extensions may interfere with other users' accounts if enabled (purposely for you); that adds up to the current challenge: enabling further extensions than the default ones provided and made available by your hosting provider for shared account users.

You should consider contacting them (your hosting provider) so as to enquire whether they meet server requirements for Laravel; it is the first thing you should do before considering to acquire their services so as to enable you choose the right host for your project.

Once that is done and you are certain they do, you will have more rooms to truly assess and proceed with your project.